# Beam Convergence?

Tags: physics, super-powers, light, lasers

I have a character that can release laser beams from both his hands and i just want to know if he can shoot these 2 lasers at a single point and converge causing it to become a singular stronger beam.

One example of this is in Ben 10 where the Churls could shoot an optical beam that could converge with all their species beams to create a giant beam.
Or the Deathstar.

Since light can't converge. What substance (or characterised type of substance e.g. extreme heat, extreme density, can interact with other matter, etc,) can my character shoot out to get this affect e.g. plasma.

https://ben10.fandom.com/wiki/Churl

Comment: "... shoot these lasers at a single point and converge causing it to become a singular stronger beam." Like the Death Star superlaser?

Comment: kind of i guess

Comment: What makes you think that you cannot direct two lasers onto the same location?

Comment: There are a couple of things you might be thinking. If you're talking about aiming multiple lasers at a single location, then that's a standard technique for burning out cancer tumors. (x-ray lasers, of course) If you're taking about them meeting at a random spot and joining forces for the rest of the trip, then no. Photons are bosons, and can't interact with each other.

Comment: There are a great many questions on Physics.SE to the effect of "what happens when electrons collide" and on a human scale the answer, boringly enough, is "not very much". If you had a high-energy physics lab you might be able to detect the vanishingly small number that [become weird bits of antimatter](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/1364). Otherwise, they pass through each other.

Comment: Do you expect your "giant beam" to be stronger than the sum of its parts? What is the point of bothering to try and merge both beams in one rather than directly shooting both of them at the target?

Comment: @BarbaudJulien You can melt iron at 1500°C, but you can't melt it if you raise temperature to 1000°C at two different points. Having merged beams ensure that both beams strike the same target with greater "penetration" as long as the beam hit, and you don't need to target accurately with each hand this way :).

Comment: @Tortliena alleviating the accuracy issue is a good point

Answer (score 4):

**We need to clear something up**

If what you're thinking looks anything at all like the following picture, the answer is no.

[image]
*Image courtesy [Centives.net](http://www.centives.net/S/2012/how-much-would-it-cost-to-build-the-death-star/).*

That kind of "convergence" is Hollywood-only and has nothing at all to do with real physics.

**Light can always converge... at a single point**

Light can only converge on a single point *on a surface.* Whether it's two hands or two flashlights or two laser pointers. For convenience, let's assume the surface is always opaque. The two beams "converge" at a single point on the opaque surface, combine, and stop. If they're bright/intense enough, they can heat the surface or even cut through it... but that's another issue.

But let's assume that single point is somewhere in the air between me and, oh, let's say, that tree over there. Does the light "converge?"

Nope.

While it's theoretically possible that an occasional photon or two might collide and do something unusually cool, the statistical truth is that the two beams pass right through each other and keep on goin'. I'd have to see the math to believe they'd even significantly heat the air at the point the two beams cross (cross, not converge).

**So the real answer to your question is probably, "no."**

*But should that stop you???*

Heck, no! It worked for Lucas, so it can work for you, too. That's the magic of worldbuilding, you set the rules for what's "true" in your world.

BTW, if you want to see something along the lines of exactly what you're talking about in action, track down a copy of [Dr. Strange (1978)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Strange_%281978_film%29) (yeah, you read that right... *1978.* Cold war, Wang computers... good times!). If I recall the movie correctly, his side kick does the two-hands-beam-weapon thing. Fun movie.

Comment: They would heat the air at focal point exactly as the sum of the individual pencils of light, not more, not less.

Comment: With a reasonable powered pulsed laser and a reasonable lens you will see a spark  and hear a pop as the air is ionized....

Answer (score 2):

Light can converge and diverge, as anybody who uses lenses can tell you.

Laser is not different, it can converge or diverge, providing that a suitable lens is available.

The only difference is that, being laser a coherent beam, two different beams interacting with each other in a defined volume will produce a constant interference, depending of the phase difference between the two beams: if the two beams arrive with the same phase they will add up their energy, while if the phase is opposite they will cancel each other, with all the gradation in between.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that third paragraph.

Comment: @MaelstromV The keywords are constructive and destructive interference. If you have a laser gun and it shoots two lasers out of the same barrel then the lasers might add up to get a twice as powerful beam (constructive interference). But if the beams are out of sync they might add up to produce a less powerful beam than before (destructive interference). The two lasers waste energy battling each other and less gets to the target.

Answer (score 1):

In order for laser beams from separate sources to converge, they have to intersect and change direction. But unless affected by an external force, the photons in the laser beams will keep travelling in straight lines. They won't bump into each other like two streams of liquid, but instead will pass right through each other. Some things that can change the direction of light are lenses, mirrors, and very strong gravity (like a black hole).

It's true that a combined beam wouldn't be stronger, but it would look cooler. If you want the full force of realistic hand lasers in a single beam, you'd just **put your hands together**. Right, not as cool looking, but there are practical reasons to do it, and your character gets to show off how smart they are! If you need to punch a hole through a thick or really stubborn material, you want the light to hit at the same angle. You might even cup your hands or hold them out clapped together to deliver all that energy to a narrow point!

---

By the way, visible light, microwaves, radio waves, x-rays, gamma rays, and radiation are just names for photons of different energy levels. A laser means they are travelling parallel to each other, and a maser is just a laser in the microwave frequency range. If your character can vary the frequency of light emitted, they could use an invisible high energy attack, or could cook something from the inside out with microwaves. Read more about [the whole spectrum on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_spectrum).

---

If you must have beams that curve and merge, you probably want **[plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma)**, like a [Star Wars blaster](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Blaster). Superhot ionized matter would flow along magnetic fields and curve how you describe. But with plasma blast hands, it would probably still be more effective to put your hands together -- perhaps the extra effort of more complex magnetic fields is worth it because you can gather and superheat the air more effectively when your hands are apart.